# How to define destination for an append query Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to append two tables in MS Access at the moment. This is my SQL View of my Query at the moment:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable
SELECT 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.University = Table2.University;
```

Where university is the only field name that would have similarities between the two tables. When I try and run the query, I get this error:

```
Query must have at least one destination field.
```

I assumed that the `INSERT INTO MainTable` portion of my SQL was defining the destination, but apparently I am wrong. I am not a very frequent Access user, or database administrator at all, really - I was just tasked with this at work and do not want to disappoint, therefore, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MainTable has more that one colum (I guess it does), then you need to specify it like that:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable(ColumnName)
```

Also you have to specify the columns in the SELECT STATEMENT:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM TABLE2....
```